File and Directory Access Under .NET MAUI
We have a Xamarin app that we are porting to .NET MAUI (.net 8 Android).  Historically, we save the application DATA in an external folder to facilitate trouble shooting, customer support and upgrade flexibility.
One scenario is that at startup, we may copy or move a folder created by an earlier version of that app to an archive under the Documents folder. The new version will need to on occasion, access the archives.
What we are finding is that while we can easily create and access external data in Documents created by the same version of the app, if we attempt to read data that was created by a previous version of the app, it fails.
Does anyone have an idea as to why a newer version of the app cannot read data created by an earlier version under .NET MAUI?  This would SEEM to be related to permission attributes on the folders or files themselves... (?) ... but that's an assumption.
Any insights on this (and how to make the older archives read/writable?)
exception caught after read attempt
the exception
examining contents with device explorer
stack trace

what does "it fails" mean?  Do you get an exception or error?  Does it crash?

@Jason : The read fails.  No crash... but the read throws an exception with an "access denied" message.  Accessing the same file, the same location (under "Documents"), but created by the current version  of the app, is just fine.

Can you access those files on the Documents ? I meant go to that directory and try to open one of them by any editor

@MustafaMutasim : Yes.  I can create, read and write from the app that first created them, and I can open them with notepad, etc.   But if they were created by a previous version of the app, an attempt to read throws an access denied exception.  I have checked the permissions on the files in question (with Android Studio Device Explorer and they are all  rw-rw-xx)

Please Edit your Question and Upload screenshot if possible, For Exception & Folder

Need exception details to be sure what the issue is

@MustafaMutasim Done

@FreakyAli : See images in question

Another observation while attempting to understand this:  I used adb to shell into the device. I went to the folder in question and created a file ("echo hello > somefile.txt").  Then ran the mobile app in the debugger and changed the file name to open to that file - and it works.  Also: the original file in that directory is not visible via "ls -ali" ... but if I attempt to write or delete the file, I get an access denied.  This clearly has something to do with the ownership placed on the files when they were originally creawted.  But how to change?

What do I do with the image if there is no stacktrace? Guess the issue?

@FreakyAli : Stack trace added.  I'm sure that will help.  Thank-you.

Brother the stack trace is usually way too big to fit in an image as it as text into the question itself

This doc might help, File Storage and Access with Xamarin.Android

The OP has succinctly stated the issue, which I can confirm is a recent change in behavior. I'm here because I'm having the same issue. I need to read a document in external storage when the app launches for the very first time, which was not created by the app.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. From Review
